# How to insert double quotes to a string vector that is being passed to a paste function?

Tags: r, split

I have a loop of data.frames and I wish to convert them into long format. I have certain strings stored in a vector that I intend to pass them as `id.vars` for the `melt()` statement.

Here are the four data.frames, reproduced

```
df1<-structure(list(Year = 2012L, Area = "South", TopSumOfCount = 780L), .Names = c("Year", 
"Area", "TopSumOfCount"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list(Year = 2012L, Category = "Condiments", TopSumOfCount = 780L), .Names = c("Year", 
"Category", "TopSumOfCount"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

df3<-structure(list(Year = 2012L, Area = "South", TopSumOfCount = 780L), .Names = c("Year", 
"Area", "TopSumOfCount"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

df4<-structure(list(Year = 2012L, Category = "Condiments", TopSumOfCount = 780L), .Names = c("Year", 
"Category", "TopSumOfCount"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

AllDF_Names<-c("df1","df2","df3","df4")
```

To present it in a long format, I needed to use a `melt()` and I encountered the need for using a combination function.The id.vars to be used is stored in a vector and I wish to keep it that way!

So, I used this `dQuote` to try insert a double quote after splitting the string "Year,Area", with an attempt to get a string like "c(\"Year\",\"Area\")"

```
ParticipantsForMelt<-c("Year,Area", "Year,Category", "Year,Area", "Year,Category")
 for(i in 1:length(AllDF_Names){


 MeltStatement[i]<-paste0(AllDF_Names[i],"_long<-melt(",
               AllDF_Names[i],",","id.vars=",
               dQuote(strsplit(ParticipantsForMelt[i],",")),")")
 eval(parse(text=MeltStatement[i]))
}
```

The problem in the above code is I'm getting the double quotes in an unusual position : (notice the double quotes before c(...) in the result)

```
df1_long<-melt(df1,id.vars=“c(\"Year\", \"Area\")”)
```

Desired output :

```
df1_long<-melt(df1,id.vars=c(\"Year\", \"Area\"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An way of doing this is writing a little function and then apply gsub:

```
addDoubleQuotes <- function(...)as.character(sys.call())[-1]

b=addDoubleQuotes(c("Year,Area", "Year,Category", "Year,Area", "Year,Category"))

> b
[1] "c(\"Year,Area\", \"Year,Category\", \"Year,Area\", \"Year,Category\")"

> gsub(",", '", "',b)

[1] "c(\"Year\", \"Area\"\", \" \"Year\", \"Category\"\", \" \"Year\", \"Area\"\", \" \"Year\", \"Category\")"
```

Comment: I can't pass the variable name as the argument,.`b=addDoubleQuotes(ParticipantsForMelt)` gives me `"ParticipantsForMelt"`